# Compose MDC Theme Adapter doesn't convert every color correctly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, android-styles

I'm following [this guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-compose-theme-adapter) to convert my xml colors to Compose Theme. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to get the correct colors. Somehow I receive the default android color palette.

I tested Checkbox and Switch Composable widgets. The tinted color of theirs is wrong. Am I doing something wrong?

For Checkbox `checkedColor` is using `secondary`.
For Switch `checkedThumbColor` is using `secondaryVariant`.

```
<color name="ui7">#212B36</color>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/ui7</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/ui7</item>
```

But, Checkbox checkedColor looks like it's black
and Switch checkedThumbColor looks like it's default android green.

The weird part is that the adapter works for primaryColor. CircularProgressIndicator has the correct color on it.

[image: UI Screen]

MyFragment.kt:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup): View {
    return ComposeView(container.context).apply {
        setContent {
            MainTheme {
                Scaffold(topBar = topAppbar("My Toolbar Title")) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(it),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    ) {
                        Switch(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
                            checked = checkedState.value,
                            onCheckedChange = onValueChanged,
                        )
                        Checkbox(checked = true, onCheckedChange = onValueChanged)

                        RadioButton(selected = true, onClick = { { /*TODO*/ } })
                        OutlinedButton(onClick = {}) {
                            Text("Outlined Button")
                        }
                        FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                                contentDescription = "Localized description"
                            )
                        }
                        CircularProgressIndicator(0.4f)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Theme.kt:

```
@Composable
fun MainTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    var (colors, type) = createMdcTheme(context, layoutDirection)
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Switch.kt:

```
object SwitchDefaults {
    @Composable
    fun colors(
        checkedThumbColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant,
        checkedTrackColor: Color = checkedThumbColor,
        checkedTrackAlpha: Float = 0.54f,
        uncheckedThumbColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        uncheckedTrackColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
        uncheckedTrackAlpha: Float = 0.38f,
        disabledCheckedThumbColor: Color = checkedThumbColor
```

Checkbox.kt:

```
object CheckboxDefaults {
    /**
     * Creates a [CheckboxColors] that will animate between the provided colors according to the
     * Material specification.
     *
     * @param checkedColor the color that will be used for the border and box when checked
     * @param uncheckedColor color that will be used for the border when unchecked
     * @param checkmarkColor color that will be used for the checkmark when checked
     * @param disabledColor color that will be used for the box and border when disabled
     * @param disabledIndeterminateColor color that will be used for the box and
     * border in a [TriStateCheckbox] when disabled AND in an [ToggleableState.Indeterminate] state.
     */
    @Composable
    fun colors(
        checkedColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
        uncheckedColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
        checkmarkColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        disabledColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
        disabledIndeterminateColor: Color = checkedColor.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)
    )
```

styles.xml:
[image: styles.xml]